# Swift Cocoa send notification to app through PHP

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsnotifications

my application downloads data from a database in the viewDidLoad, yet I need the application to be notified when the data is changed in said database. As my server and database are programmed in PHP, how can I send through PHP a notification to my COCOA app? Thanks

Comment: A detailed answer to this question would be very lengthy, but let me show you the references of [Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html). You can send APNS notifications to notify your app about changes.

Comment: Is the app and server running on the same machine? If so, you could create a Foundation tool (i.e. command-line executable) that the PHP script could invoke. The tool would then post a distributed notification, that your app could observe. See `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. A more sophisticated solution would involve creating an XPC service to pass the information.The PHP could also push data to a named pipe, that the app could read in the background.